# MPI Programming C++, Specific Sequence for process based on rank

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing, message-passing

I am new to MPI programming and I wrote the following code to check the ranks so when I run a code, It randomly selects any one of the processor at a time. 
so when I do an MPI run I get the follow outputs(I ran it for two instances) processor number i.e -np 10
I get the following output:
Instance 1:
$ mpirun -np 10 L2
Rank 2
Rank 7
Rank 5
Rank 1
Rank 4
Rank 9
Rank 0
Rank 3
Rank 8
Rank 6

Instance 2:
$ mpirun -np 10 L2

Rank 4
Rank 2
Rank 1
Rank 9
Rank 5
Rank 3
Rank 0
Rank 6
Rank 8
Rank 7

I would like to know if there is any way I can start with a specific processor and follow in sequence , increment 1 to each for example: if I wish to start with 6 then the output should be as follows:

Rank 6
Rank 7
Rank 8
Rank 9
Rank 0
Rank 1
Rank 2
Rank 3
Rank 4
Rank 5

Thanks!

Shubh
Coder GeEk :P

Below is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int rank, size;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
cout<<"Rank "<<rank<<endl; mpi_finalize();
}
```

Tellme if I was able to explain my problem clearly or I will edit it to explain it better way.

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579563/serialize-mpi-threads

Comment: Communicate an int and prinr sth only with the process with that rank id.

Comment: Thanks...@user3384414, but that uses a for loop,I have done that... can we do it using command line..like I just found out we can use the following: mpirun -np 10 l2 --rank-by....this "--rank-by" does it in round-robin fashion but I need the starting rank to be specific to what I mention in command line, so if I mention 5 then the sequence should be 5,6,7,8,9...so on  @Maikel - I didnt get u "communicate an int and print sth" meaning??new to mpi so ur help is highly appreciated...

Comment: There are plenty of solutions. You can use multiple `MPI_Barrier()` like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579563/serialize-mpi-threads , you can use a token sent by rank `r` to rank `(r+1)%size`, you can use `MPI_Gatherv()` to gather the different arrays of char from the different processors and print it at once... Which one are you trying to implement? My guess is that there is no predefined option to print stuffs in an ordered fashion. And it is hard to write C++/MPI without using `for` loops!

Comment: No matter how well you synchronise the MPI ranks, as long as you are printing to the standard output from different ranks, there is **absolutely no guarantee** regarding the order of the text in the final output.